# Shared Entry Event in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Hello  Has anybody used Shared Entry Events in Journey Builder? I am trying to think of a real time use case where this can be used.

Comment: Any suggestions here experts?

Answer (score 1):

if you create a new Version for example and you want to start the new version of the journey without stopping the old version you need a shared event because you will get a error message because you can't use the event in 2 Journeys at the same time.

Best

Patrick